# How to add existing form to new menu form in C# so with button click I can open it from menu screen

Tags: c#, .net, window

I am doing a project for a gym which include multiple forms and I need to add an exiting form to the main menu page so with click on membership form it can open membership form. I am able to open another form with the following code like so

```
    {
        this.Hide();
        var form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
        form2.Show();
    }
```

but I'm not able to open an existing one. Please help I have been stuck on this thing for the last 3 days.

Comment: Is this WinForms? Your `form2` is inaccessible after you leave the block. You should call `return form2` at the end of your method and save it in the caller. Then the caller should call `.Show()` on the returned value.

Comment: it is Window.Net(desktop) . but I am not able to understand where should put this code , should I put on button click

Comment: There's not enough here to understand what you are doing. You need to get a book or tutorial; this stuff is simply too complicated to make things up as you go.